# asp.net gridview control and making a gridview length smaller

Tags: asp.net, gridview, controls

Hey guys i wanted to ask is it possible to custmize the width of the gridview? 
I need to make it alot smaller to fit just right with the rest of my website. 
Things that might help are having the option to make the headers 2 rows instead of 1  also making each header use minimal space ( some are having empty space on the left and/or right side  ).
So far i didnt manage to find how to do any of those things, but i did make it shorter by making much shorter names for some of the headers but its still not enough.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this....

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-left" HeaderStyle-Width="80px">
```

DO the width adjustment similarly in rest of the c0lumns.

Answer (score 0):

Hey since it advices me not to delete the post ill just post why it got resolved. I noticed that the gridview control for asp.net has actully auto scaling with minimum size and the blank space on the header is caused only when the fields below got bigger width. So i wont be able to make it any smaller unless i make a smaller font, even shorter word etc.